# Using array formula and countif to lookup based on specific cells

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to embed a `countif` into an array formula in Google Sheets.  I'm using the `countif` command to count the number of cells on another page with a given text string, stored in column B.  Column B just contains a list of titles.  The concatenate portion does a general keyword lookup.

Here is the formula that does not work.  It just returns a 0 in each cell, which tells me the `countif` statement is failing.

```
=arrayformula(IF(B2:B<>"",COUNTIF(Registrations!C:C,(CONCATENATE("*", B2, "*"))),""))
```

If I pull out the `countif` statement, it works fine by itself.

```
=COUNTIF(Registrations!C:C,(CONCATENATE("*", B2, "*")))
```

I have even tried referencing B2:B in place of the B2 cell reference, but that does not work. What did I do wrong in the array formula statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `&` instead of the `CONCATENATE` function and referencing to `B2:B` in place of only `B2`?

The formula should look like this:

`=arrayformula(IF(B2:B<>"",COUNTIF(Registrations!C:C,("*" & B2:B & "*")),""))`

It works for me.

This is my 'Registrations' sheet:

[image]

And this is the sheet where the formula is written:

[image]

Comment: I had actually tried that, but I must have done them individually and not together (the & and B2:B).  Combining both worked perfectly.  Thanks!